# Remove certain links from a textfile by reading textfile

Tags: python, text-files, with-statement

So I have **whitelist.txt** which contains some links, and **scrapedlist.txt** which contains other links, and also links that are in **whitelist.txt.**

I'm trying to open and read **whitelist.txt** and then open and read **scrapedlist.txt** - to write to a new file **updatedlist2.txt** which will have all the contents of **scrapedlist.txt** minus ***whitelist.txt.***

I'm pretty new to Python, so still learning. I've searched for answers, and this is what I came up with:

```
def whitelist_file_func():
    with open("whitelist.txt", "r") as whitelist_read:
        whitelist_read.readlines()
    whitelist_read.close()

    unique2 = set()

    with open("scrapedlist.txt", "r") as scrapedlist_read:
        scrapedlist_lines = scrapedlist_read.readlines()
    scrapedlist_read.close()

    unique3 = set()

    with open("updatedlist2.txt", "w") as whitelist_write2:
   
        for line in scrapedlist_lines:
            if unique2 not in line and line not in unique3:
                whitelist_write2.write(line)
                unique3.add(line)
```

I get this error and I'm also not sure if I'm doing it the right way:

```
if unique2 not in line and line not in unique3:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set
```

What should I do to achieve the above-mentioned and also is my code right?

EDIT:

**whitelist.txt:**

```
KUWAIT
ISRAEL
FRANCE
```

**scrapedlist.txt:**

```
USA
CANADA
GERMANY
KUWAIT
ISRAEL
FRANCE
```

**updatedlist2.txt (this is how it should be):**

```
USA
CANADA
GERMANY
```

Comment: What is purpose of unique2? You don't even fill it with values anywhere

Comment: Oh, that was to store the lines of whitelist.txt? Am I wrong?

Comment: You never do anything with whitelist_read.readlines() either.. you're not assigning it to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I applied some changes to your code.

1. `readlines()` method is replaced with `read().splitlines()`. Both of them read the whole file and convert each line to a list item. The difference is `readlines()` include `\n` at the end of items.
2. `unique2` and `unique3` are removed. I couldn't find their usage.
3. By two first parts `whitelist_lines` and `scrapedlist_lines` are two lists that contain links. Based on your description we need lines of `scrapedlist_lines` that are not in the `whitelist_lines` list so condition `if unique2 not in line and line not in unique3:` changed to `if line not in whitelist_lines:`.
4. If you are using Python 2.5 and higher the close() can be called for you automatically using the with statement.

The final code is:

```
with open("whitelist.txt", "r") as whitelist_read:
    whitelist_lines = whitelist_read.read().split("\n")
    
with open("scrapedlist.txt", "r") as scrapedlist_read:
    scrapedlist_lines = scrapedlist_read.read().split("\n")

with open("updatedlist2.txt", "w") as whitelist_write2:
    for line in scrapedlist_lines:
        if line not in whitelist_lines:
            whitelist_write2.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: No, we only need updatedlist2.txt with the contents of scrapedlist.txt minus whitelist.txt because scrapedlist.txt also contains what whitelist.txt does.

Comment: I think we both say the same thing. In programming way the code calculate `updatedlist2.txt = scrapedlist.txt - whitelist.txt` :) please check the output of the code and if there is a problem. tell me by example. Thanks.

Comment: I checked. It contains the contents of whitelist.txt still, but the file size is less not sure what changed though, but the new file shouldn't have the contents of whitelist.txt.

Comment: Can you attach some parts of your files to the question? I mean `whitelist.txt` and `scrapedlist.txt` files. Then we can test with real data.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: My bad. It is working fine! My apologies. I'm new :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) Wish you good times with python :D

Comment: No need for close since you're using the with context manager.

Comment: Thanks, your comment applied to the answer.